# How do I use constants in a PowerShell module?

Tags: powershell, variables, module

I want to declare some variables as global constants in a module (web service response codes). The problem is, when I import the module (more than once, either with or without `-Force`) I get

```
Import-Module : Cannot remove variable ADDED_INCLUSION_STATUS because it is
constant or read-only. If the variable is read-only, try the operation
again specifying the Force option.
```

What workaround/approach can I use?

My declaration looks like this:

```
Set-Variable -name STATUS_ABORTED -value 0 -Scope Global -option Constant
```

Comment: Did you flag them as `Constant` or `Read-Only`?  As the error message says, `Read-Only` variables can be forcibly removed (though, I'm not sure PowerShell will do this for you behind the scenes).  Alternatively, does it help if you `Remove-Module` before re-importing?

Comment: I like this question and it is not _lacking_ code, as your text describes anything one needs to know to reproduce. However I would really love to see an [mcve] which attracts more users to test your case and to troubleshoot your problem

Comment: How are you declaring your constants?

Comment: `Remove-Module` doesn't help.

Comment: Check whether the variable exists before trying to (re)define it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your declaration to:

```
Set-Variable -name STATUS_ABORTED -value 0 -Scope Global -Option ReadOnly -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

A ReadOnly variable can be redefined by using the `-Force` switch. A Constant is there for the duration of the session. These cannot be changed or removed without closing PowerShell.